# hide and display select tag by toggling other select tag

Tags: jquery

I want to display an select option tag based on my first selected option.
Here is my working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49nh5an6/)

```
<select id="main">
<option>all</option>
<option clas="first_opt">first</option>
<option class="second_opt">second</option>
<option class="third_opt">third</option>
</select>

<select id="sub_first" class="sub">
<option>sub 1</option>
<option>sub 1</option>
</select>

$(".sub").hide();
$("#main").change(function() {
var val = $(this).val();
$(".sub").hide();
if( val ) {
    $("#sub_" + val).show();   
}
})
```

But I dont think it is a perfect coding because for example, if the value of the main select option contains two or more than one letter such as "first opt" then my code doesnt work anymore. So I think it will be better if I can get the class value of the main option instead. But I couldn't make it works. Please help

`

Comment: you need to share your code in the question... not just a demo link

Comment: Links to other sites that show your code can be broken. Please post at least enough of your code to demonstrate the problem. Along with that, the link to the working example is fine.

Comment: I think you already implemented it in correct way... programming logic depends on individual thinking and this could be different. So what is your exact problem here?

Comment: oh sorry. My first time here so when it asked for code, I didnt know what to do since I didnt see other people posted their code when they shared their Jsfiddle. My bad

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: if I have an <option>other opt</option> then it wont work anymore. I think it will be better if the code is more flexible. So I try to get the class value of the option tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working now because of you haven't added `value` attribute in `option`. So `$(this).val()` returning your `option text value`

Made some changes in markup value attribute added in `option`: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/49nh5an6/2/)

```
<select id="main">
    <option>all</option>
    <option class="first" value="first">first opt</option><!--value added-->
    <option class="second" value="second">second opt</option><!--value added-->
    <option class="third" value="third">third opt</option><!--value added-->
</select>

<select id="sub_first" class="sub">
    <option>sub 1</option>
    <option>sub 1</option>
</select>

<select id="sub_second" class="sub">
    <option>sub 2</option>
    <option>sub 2</option>
</select>

<select id="sub_third" class="sub">
    <option>sub 3</option>
    <option>sub 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code you can use className instead.

```
$("#main").change(function() {
    var val = this.className;
    $(".sub").hide();

    if( val ) {
        $("#sub_" + val).show();   
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
$(".sub").hide();

$("#main").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().indexOf(' '));

    $(".sub").hide();

    if( val ) {
        $("#sub_" + val).show();   
    }
})
```

have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/zfhLnpkp/